# converting a single integer number input to a list in python

Tags: python, list, input

I am looking for a single line command in python to convert an integer input to list.
The following is the situation.

```
mylist=[]
mylist=list(input('Enter the numbers: '))
```

The above line works perfectly if i give more than one number as input. Eg 1,2,3 . But it gives Error when i give only a single digit entry. Eg:  1   . Saying it cannot convert an integer to list.
I don't want to run a loop asking user for each input. So i want a one line command which will work for *one* or *more* digits input given by user separated by commas.

Thanking you,
-indiajoe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the simplest thing that you can do is:

```
mylist = map(int, raw_input('Enter the numbers: ').split(','))
```

But it's nearly the same that using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `raw_input` and convert to `int` with a list comprehension:

```
user_input = raw_input('Enter the numbers: ')
my_list = [int(i) for i in user_input.split(',')]
```

From the [offical documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input): `raw_input` *reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.*

Comment: You can also use eval to convert your string list to int: mylist = map(eval, mylist)

Comment: Thanks, but i was trying to precisely avoid this loop. Isn't there any one liner for this common use? If not, I shall go ahead with this loop method.

Comment: @SRC: It's a bad practice to use eval on a user input! You should do that only if **really** needed and with the necessary check.

Comment: @indiajoe: You will have the loop anyway, could be hidden inside map but there will be anyway! Given so, to choose between a list comprehension or map (or filter etc...) is mearly a matter of taste. Nevertheless you should be aware that in python-3 `map` is a generator expression so in case one day you'll find yourself porting your own code just remember to wrap map with list (if you need a list and not a generator), like `list(map(...))`.

Comment: @RikPoggi: Thanks for the info regd the python 3.

Answer (score 1):

`input` `eval()`'s what you type.  So, when you type `1,2,3`, the result is a `tuple`; when you type `1`, the result is an `int`.  Try typing `1,` instead of `1`.  Note that your first line (`mylist=[]`) is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, typing a comma after integer works. Eg: 1, But looks a little untidy to ask a user to put extra comma. Or I will have to add a try: except: block to catch it and correct.

Comment: Following this approach, this will work: 
`mylist=list(eval(raw_input('Enter the numbers: ')+','))`. (Doing the `eval` with `raw_input` and the comma).